# How To Resize UITextField According to the Content in iOS7?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, xcode5.1

Although i Have got many Links for how to Resize UITextField according To Content Added inside it,my TextField's is Not Growing with the Text.May be I am missing out Something.
I have Also Tried this Method Which i Got While Searching For this issue,still it is not working.I know i am missing out Something.But not Getting What Exactly.

```
- (IBAction) textFieldDidChange: (UITextField*) textField
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        [textField invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }];
}
```

i am Using Xcode 5.1.1 for iOS7 compatibility.
Can anyone help What i am missing Out?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use Textview instead of textfield.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the height of text field but you cannot use more than one line of data in text field instead you can use textview as given below:

```
UITextView *textView=[UITextView alloc]init];
textView.frame= CGRectMake(20,20, 455, 80);
textView.layer.cornerRadius=6;
textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
textView.layer.borderWidth=1;
textView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
textView.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
textView.editable=YES;
[self.view addSubView:textView];
```